# Android 3.0 Virtual Machine on Win7 64bit

Tags: android-emulator

When I'm running the AVD 3.0 out of eclipse on win7 64bit it often stuck(not responding).

It has a cpu usage of 25% all time. When I quit the adb, the cpu usage lower.

I installed a database app and now closing adb give me no more solution.

Is 3.0 buggy?

K R, Aileen

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to install other AVD .. if the problem persists try to play with the settings for your AVD, try to allocate more RAM to your device, play with the heap size and check what happens with you

Comment: The other AVD's 1.6-2.2 act normally. They run fine with less resources. I tried 512MB and it wasn't the answer. When I don't use adb at startup it is worse.